# What should the morphisms in the Category of Directed Sets be?

Tags: ct.category-theory, gn.general-topology, order-theory, limits-and-convergence, nets

[Directed sets](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/direction) are defined to be sets equipped with a preorder that admit (finitary) upper bounds e.g. pairs $(D, \preceq)$ such that $\forall p,q \in D$ there exists $r \in D$ such that $p \preceq r$ and $q \preceq r$. Equivalently, they may be defined as thin categories in which every finite diagram admits a cocone.

In either case, there is some intuition as to what a morphism of directed sets ought to be: in the first case, perhaps monotone functions; in the second, a functor such that there exists a cocone over any finite diagram that maps to a cocone over the image.

However, these aren't the only two descriptions of directed sets nor are the two suggested definitions equivalent.  Finally, I haven't been able to find a source which describes a (the?) category of directed sets.  Is there a consensus on the 'right' definition of a morphism of directed sets?  Further, are there any good resources on the properties of the category of directed sets?

Comment: When using directed sets to take limits of points in topology or taking direct limits, it is well known that the limit is the same if you only consider a cofinal portion of the directed set. Therefore in the category of directed sets, each directed set should be isomorphic to any cofinal subset. I suspect that the category of directed sets is related to the Tukey ordering on directed sets. I will probably answer this question soon once I figure everything out.

Comment: Also, the category of directed sets should be a full subcategory of the category of filtrant categories (whatever that is) since the notion of a filtrant category is the categorization of the notion of a directed set. By the way, this is an interesting question.

Comment: Thanks Joeseph! It's been sitting in the back of my mind for a couple days.

Comment: Look here http://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/runkel/ss13-fose.html
for a collection of papers of Douglas et al.

The morphisms are there continuous set maps between direct intervals.

Comment: Doesn't the answer to the question depend ultimately on what you want to do with this category? I can imagine different uses of the class of directed sets, which have different natural morphisms.

Comment: «The right category» surely depends on what you want to it for, as Joel observes.

Comment: Joel and Mariano, I agree with the one caveat I mentioned in the question.  Specifically, I asked after a consensus.  Thus far, it seems I can continue on my merry way categorizing the class as I choose...in terms of cofinal mappings.  Though I will be looking into the Tukey ordering as it's new to me. Mostly, this question is meant to feel out what the community thinks when the phrase "category of directed sets" comes up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a partial answer.

Given a directed set $D$, we say that a subset $A\subseteq D$ is cofinal if for each $d\in D$ there is some $a\in A$ with $d\leq a$. We say that $A\subseteq D$ is bounded if $A\subseteq\downarrow d=\{x\in D|x\leq d\}$ for some $d\in D$ and we say that $A$ is unbounded if it is not bounded.  Let $D,E$ be two directed sets. Then we say that a function $f:D\rightarrow E$ (not necessarily order preserving) is a cofinal map (also called a convergent map) if the image of every cofinal subset of $D$ is a cofinal subset of $E$. A function $g:E\rightarrow D$ (not necessarily order preserving) is said to be unbounded (also called a Tukey map) if the image of every unbounded subset of $E$ is an unbounded subset of $D$. If $D,E$ are posets, then there is an unbounded map $f:D\rightarrow E$ if and only if there is a cofinal map $g:E\rightarrow D$, and in either case we say that $D$ is Tukey reducible to $E$ and we write $D\leq_{T}E$. The Tukey ordering $\leq_{T}$ in a sense measures how big your directed set is. Clearly the class of directed sets can be made a category where the morphisms are either the cofinal maps or the unbounded maps, and these categories are enough for us to define the Tukey ordering. I conjecture that one can take a quotient category of one of these categories to get a more natural category of directed sets(i.e. where a directed set is isomorphic to each of its cofinal subsets), but I don't see how exactly to go about this. Perhaps someone else will give a better and more complete answer to this question.

Comment: Thanks for this Joseph.  I'm reading about the Tukey ordering now.